# Javascript confirm offset on a touch screen

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen

I have put together a kiosk consisting of a Raspberry pi 3 running Raspbian and a Hanns.G HT231HPB touch screen monitor to display a web page, because I don't want inadvertent submission I have locked a lot of the links down with Javascript confirm, these work, but the touch point is significantly offset to above the button which makes it difficult for the users. does anybody have any suggestions for controlling this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected this is the hardware and Raspbian failing to work well enough together. Set up the same screen with a mini PC running Windows 10 and Chrome, and eventually a PI 3 running Windows 10 IOT and the screens responsiveness improved exponentially. So the screen does support Raspbian, but only in a very primitive way and both the full and stripped down windows gave a better front end response on the touch screen.